# ABBYY Flexicapture ODBC export date field to DATE type column

Tags: abbyy

In ABBYY Flexicapture, I use the ODBC-Compatible database option to export to my SQL Server database. Several of my columns in the database are `DATETIME`, but I recently realized, we don't need (nor have) the time, and would like to export only the date. So I changed the database column to a `DATE` type. Now I'm getting this error:

`Failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

I am not providing it with a time, only a date. Historically, these have gone into the database with 00:00:00 as the time associated with the date.

How can I export to `DATE` column?

Comment: Curse this ridiculous issue...

Answer (score 1):

Have never faced such issue in FC. First make sure that ODBC driver is from the drivers list they recommend

For SQL 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012 database:

Provider - OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers;
 Note: Selecting "OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" may cause problems when working with certain data types and long fields.

Driver - SQL Server. 
For Access 2003, 2007, 2010 database:

Provider - OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers; Driver - Microsoft Access Driver (Driver do Microsoft Access or Microsoft Access-Treiber). 
For Oracle 9g, 10g, 11g database:

Provider - Oracle Provider for OLE DB;
Selecting the driver is not required.

Second try to reset the export destination. Select the ODBC source and map fields again